# linkbutton are not posting back in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, linkbutton

I have many `linkbutton` placed on a webform everything working correctly til yesterday. But now now my ajax extenders are not working and `linkbuttons` are posting back.
some of my code is

```
 <table  width="460px">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" 
            style=" color: #C48239; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Bookman Old Style'; text-align:center;height:22px;">
           Manage Your Profile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_per_pro" runat="server" CssClass="linkButton" 
                PostBackUrl="~/User/Edit_profile.aspx">Edit Personal Profile</asp:LinkButton> </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_par_pro" runat="server"  CssClass="linkButton">Edit Partner's Profile</asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_con_det" runat="server" CssClass="linkButton" 
                PostBackUrl="~/User/Edit_profile.aspx">Edit Contect Details</asp:LinkButton></td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_add_photos" runat="server" CssClass="linkButton">Add Photos</asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_hob" runat="server" CssClass="linkButton" 
                PostBackUrl="~/User/Edit_profile.aspx">Edit Hobbies and Interests</asp:LinkButton></td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_del_pro" runat="server" CssClass="linkButton">Remove/Delete Profile</asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
</table></center>
</div>
</div><!-- div 2 end-->
<div id="div3">
<div id="inbox1"><b>About Myself</b>
</div>
<div id="inbox2"><a href="Partner_pre.aspx">Partner Prefrence </a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
<div id="indiv4"><b>Basics Information</b>
<div id="edit4">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_edit" runat="server" CssClass="link" 
        PostBackUrl="~/User/Edit_profile.aspx">&nbsp;Edit</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<img src="images/edit.png" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiv24">
    <div id="lt"><table class="style1" >
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #666666; width: 180px">
                Age</td>
            <td style="width: 180px">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_age2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td></tr><tr>
            <td style="color: #666666; width: 180px">
                Mobile Number</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_mob2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #666666; width: 180px">
                Height</td>
            <td style="width: 180px">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_height2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td></tr><tr>
            <td style="color: #666666; width: 180px">
                Email Id</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_eml2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #666666; width: 180px">
                Marital Status</td>
            <td style="width: 180px">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_mar_sts2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td></tr>
    </table></div>
a link is shown on hover of linkbutton 
javascript:webforms_DoPostbackWithOption:(NewPostBackoption("","false",true,"false"));
```

Comment: Any possibility that you were affected by any of these http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx ?

Comment: Which version of internet explorer?

Comment: I have tested it on IE chrome and latest version of mozila

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any validation controls inside application , check once by setting the Cause validation = false to link button control .

Answer (score 0):

Some times your system has changed to old time(like one year back) also the link buttons won't redirect

Comment: check your system date

Comment: Date is correct but i saw its format is changed does it effect the solution

Answer (score 0):

There may be validation controls inside application , check once by setting the Cause validation = false to link button control .